# Bulk export in oracle 8i

Tags: oracle, oracle8i

How can I export data from Oracle 8i database using command which I can run through oracle cli?
My biggest problem is, the data should be exported based in the query I use...
For ex,

`select * from emp where emp_id>4`

should dump the records having **emp_id>4**.

I don't have permission to use functions. 
Please help!!

Comment: You need to upgrade to a supported version (i.e. one from this century) **now**.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a set of tools that are designed for exporting data (the exp tool, for instance). These don't run via the SQL*PLUS command line (which I assume is what you mean by CLI), although they do connect via NET*8. From Oracle 8i onwards, you can use the query parameter to limit the rows exported:

`exp scott/tiger tables=emp query="where deptno=10"`

But you have to have the Oracle client installed and be able to connect to the database via SQL*NET.

If all you have is the ability to run queries, you're out of luck unless you can write a query that generates a CSV (tricky if you don't have the ability to call/write functions). It sounds to me like all you have access to is a web interface.